# Phoenix.HTML.Form does not take errors from changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have template code that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if Enum.any?(f.errors) do %>
    <%= for {attr, message} <- f.errors do %>
      <li><%= humanize(attr) %> <%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But no errors are printed even if the changeset contains errors. Here is the inspected form struct. Notice that the errors list is empty even though it was built from the changeset with errors.

```
%Phoenix.HTML.Form{data: %BlogPhoenix.Comment{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "comments">,
  content: nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, name: nil, post_id: nil,
  posts: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :posts is not loaded>,
  updated_at: nil}, errors: [], hidden: [], id: "comment",
 impl: Phoenix.HTML.FormData.Ecto.Changeset, index: nil, name: "comment",
 options: [method: "post"],
 params: %{"content" => nil, "name" => nil, "post_id" => "1"},
 source: #Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{},
  errors: [name: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]},
   content: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
  data: #BlogPhoenix.Comment<>, valid?: false>}
```

What is going on here? Shouldn't this errors list be populated?

Comment: `errors` in the changeset are ignored if `action` is `nil`. What is the value of `@action`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your changeset's :action is nil, which is what hides the errors ([see source](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto/blob/master/lib/phoenix_ecto/html.ex#L248-L249)).

The [Ecto.Changeset docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html) (under the "Changeset actions" headline) states:

> For example, frameworks such as Phoenix uses the value of changeset.action to decide if errors should be shown or not on a given form.

The docs above suggest this approach:

```
changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, %{age: 42, email: "mary@example.com"})

# Since we don't plan to call Repo.insert/2 or similar, we
# need to mimic part of its behaviour, which is to check if
# the changeset is valid and set its action accordingly if not.
if changeset.valid? do
  ... success case ...
else
  changeset = %{changeset | action: :insert} # action can be anything
  ... failure case ...
end
```

Comment: This also solved the problem with a schemaless changset, where I was using `as:` on my `form_for`.Adding the action solved the missing errors showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, `form.errors` was empty in my case despite the changeset having a non empty `errors` key.

The only other reason when this happens is when you use your `form_for` tag incorrectly. Check if you are passing a `@conn` object to your `form_for` tag when you should be passing a `@changeset` instead.

This was the cause of the issue in my case.